# MVC4 - Clearing form after submission to hide values from browser's back function

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

This is for an application that will be used in a public place for submitting data. It will not require a login. After people filling out the form are finished, I need to make sure that the back button does not reveal the form data for people who have previously filled out the form.

I've already search StackOverflow and have tried setting the header to no-cache in web.config and setting OutputStore NoCache to true. Nothing that I've tried keeps the form inputs from being seen when the back button is pressed. What's the best way to do this? I prefer not to be dependent on Javascript for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - **you can not**. If you want more detail on why there is no proper way to do this and some ideas on how to make it partially work - you might want to read this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201700/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111500-1.shtml)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for posting. From what I've read and my testing, I believe that you're right. Webkit does not seem to want to honor my no-cache (target browser is Safari on iOS). Javascript is not foolproof and bothers me on a very deep level, but I'll use it as a backup method if needed. I'll leave this open over the lunch hour and see if I get anything else before closing the question. Thanks again!